# fetching records from secondary table with specific flag mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have a tickets table and it has relation with ticket replies, one to many.
There can be three types of replies i.e note, initial-message and reply to customer.
I want to fetch all tickets where there is NO reply to customer.

using left join or group by is not returning tickets where there is no reply.

I can go with subquery but I don't want to use it. any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tickets.*
FROM tickets
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM replies
                   WHERE tickets.id = replies.ticket_id
                     AND replies.type = 'reply to customer' )
```

or

```
SELECT tickets.*
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN replies ON tickets.id = replies.ticket_id
                 AND replies.type = 'reply to customer'
WHERE replies.ticket_id IS NULL
```